# Python "Finished in 1.5s with exit code -6" when writing to HDFStore

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm running a Python script that runs many loops, each time querying the database in chunks using `pd.read_sql` and appending the DataFrame chunks to a `HDFStore` via `store.append()`.

**Problem:** In every of my 10+ runs from within Sublime Text, the script terminates with `[Finished in 1.5s with exit code -6]` but terminates after running different number of loops.

Running the same script in the command line gives

```
Abort trap: 6
```

If I were to remove the line of code that appends the chunks to the HDFStore, the script never terminates with `exit code -6`

What does the error code `-6` mean, and how can we solve the problem?

---

*Python script is being run from within Sublime Text 3 using the Anaconda IDE package for ST3.*

---

**Code Snippet**

```
import pandas as pd

store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')
for i, chunk in enumerate(pd.read_sql(query, conn, parse_dates = {'timestamp':'%Y-%m-%d'}, chunksize=1000)):
    df = chunk.fillna(value=np.nan)
    print i
    store.append('df', df)     # removing this line avoids the error
```

**Code Snippet 2**

```
store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')
store.put('df', pd.DataFrame({}), 'table') # add a node first before appending in the loop

for i, chunk in enumerate(pd.read_sql(query, conn, parse_dates = {'timestamp':'%Y-%m-%d'}, chunksize=1000)):
    df = chunk.fillna(value=np.nan)
    print i
    store.append('df', df)
```

Comment: You may need to show a bit more code for us to go on.

Comment: If it's an actual error, there should be traceback, in particular if the loop is exited prematurely. If you think your HDF library that causes the exit code, you should look up what's in the docs about documentation.

Comment: Can I guess that `pd` is `pandas` here? Since there's no pandas tag, it's vague what it is.

Comment: @Evert You are right, updated code with import statement

Comment: The documentation for [HDFStore.append()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.HDFStore.append.html) says " Node must already exist". I'm not sure about the terminology, but if `store['df']` is the node, perhaps you should try and create it first, before appending.

Comment: @Evert Updated post with `Code Snippet 2` which I believe starts off by adding an empty `pd.DataFrame` for the key `df` before the loop starts appending to the `store['df']`. Still getting the same error with `exit code -6`. There is no traceback when this happens.